# React how to make a call to an API and display an array in an array of objects PokeAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, web, pokeapi

I need help with a project i am working on, i want to be able to display the moves of a pokemon i type in, i can console.log an array of objects that have smaller arrays inside that i want to grab and display, how can i do so? ive tried the cluster of a method getPokemonNames which is supposed to get the names of the moves of the pokemon but this is where i couldnt think anymore.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import PokemonName from './PokemonName';
import axios from 'axios';


function App() {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [moves, setMoves] = useState([])
  
  const getPokemon = async (name) =>{
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`)
    const data = response.data;
    setPokemon(data);
    setMoves(data.moves);
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(data)
    getPokemonNames(data.moves)
    
   // const pokemonMovesAmount = pokemon.moves.map
  }
  const getPokemonNames = (data) =>{
    console.log(data);
    data.move.name.map((moves, key)=>(
      <div key={key}>
        <span>{moves.moves.name}</span>
      </div>
    ))
    
  }
  
  return (
    <>
    <PokemonName getPokemon={getPokemon}/>
    <div>
      {!loading && pokemon ? (<div> 
      </div>): null}
      <img src={pokemon.sprites?.front_default}/>
      <div className="container">
        {getPokemonNames}
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the pokemon name component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
const onSubmit =(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
}
export default function PokemonName(props) {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
   
    return (
        
        <div>
            <div> 
                <h1>{search}</h1>
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} type ="text" placeholder="Search for Pokemon"></input>
                <button onClick={(e) => props.getPokemon(search)}>Search</button>
                </form >
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

EDIT, this shows a bit more about the data i get back after searching up the pokemon mew
[image]

Comment: would be nice to see what type of data you get back to be able to help you a bit more

Comment: hope that helps, ive also narrowed it down to only the array of moves object

Comment: right lets go step by step, your function getPokemonNames takes a parameter data, if you notice when you call the function you are not passing anything to it, first step would be passing the data you previously stored on your state variable, if you want to see what data you have in the variable just console.log it to make sure it is what you are expecting

Comment: do you mean the function inside the return ?, i tried giving it the moves state variable but i seem to just get empty arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, making sure you pass the parameter data

```
const [moves, setMoves] = useState([])
// since you set setMoves to be data.moves second step you can iterate over data only
return (
<>
<PokemonName getPokemon={getPokemon}/>
<div>
  {!loading && pokemon ? (<div> 
  </div>): null}
  <img src={pokemon.sprites?.front_default}/>
  <div className="container">
    {getPokemonNames(moves)}
  </div>
</div>
</>
);
```

Second step, tweak your getPokemon method

```
const getPokemonNames = (data) => {
return data.map(moveD, key)=>(
  <div key={key}>
    <span>{moveD.move.name}</span>
  </div>
))
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), am i doing something wrong with the map function?

Comment: I have just edited the answer, your state variable already stores data.moves so if you do return data.map should be enough

Comment: Oh my god, you brilliant , i cant tell you how long this has been hounding me, something like 12 -15 hours, but yes it finally works, mnuch much appreciated

Comment: no problem, word of advice, make use of console logs and debuggers so you know exactly what data you are passing in etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is an mistake in your getPokemonNames . You are trying to do  data.move.name.map which means you are mapping "move" from inside "data". You need to map "moves" array. Here is how you can do it.

```
const getPokemonNames = (data) =>{
    data.moves.map(item, key)=>(
      <div key={key}>
        <span>{item.move.name}</span>
      </div>
    ))
}
```